# Bokeh datetime axis should show all yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm, ss

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I create my datetimeindex via

```
datetimes = pd.to_datetime(SeriesOfUnixtimeStamps,"s")

line(x=datetimes,y,x_axis_type="datetime",...)
```

Depending on how much I zoom in or out, the x-axis only shows lets say `:07:03` instead of `2014-06-12 12:07:03`. I want to show the whole date, not only numbers. It would be nice If one could also show it in multiple rows below the x-axis like

```
yyyy-mm-dd
hh:mm:ss
```

I thought I could apply a list of strings, but it does not work either, because it is `not in the ColumnDataSource`. If I zoom in deeper, the numbers are getting even less meaningfull. Then it might say `03`, but 03 of what? At which minute, which hour? Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment we don't have this capability, although I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh/issues/813) over on our GitHub page so you can track its progress.

The fix may be relatively simple, but we're in the midst of a SciPy release for 0.5 at the moment. We will probably get this merged in for the point release within a few weeks.